# Failed to lookup view using ejs and expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I just start learning `NodeJS` and seems amazing to me. Anyway,  I'm facing a weird issue about the view rendering. Essentially I want use the `MVC` pattern, so I organized my project in the following way:

[image]

Inside `app.js` I wrote the following code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

require('./config/environment.js')(app, express);
require('./config/routes.js')(app);

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

Essentially, I declared the server using `expressjs` 'cause is indicated for `MVC` application, and then I placed all the configuration for the environment within `envinroment.js`, passing to the constructor of the module the app and the express:

```
module.exports = function(app, express){

    app.set('development', function(){
        app.use(express.errorHandler({
            dumpExceptions: true,
            showStack: true
        }));
    });

    app.set('production', function(){
        app.use(express.errorHandler());
    });

    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.set('views', __dirname);

    if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
        app.set('port', 80);
    }
};
```

as you can see I setted as `view engine` the `ejs` package, so in this way I can render html file within a javascript file and pass information to the view.

Then in `routes.js` I wrote:

```
module.exports = function(app){

    app.get('/', function(req, res){
        res.render('home.ejs', {counter: 2});
    });

};
```

this is the code that cause the problem, infact when I load my application I get:

> Failed to lookup view "home.ejs"

I also tried using:

```
const path = require('path');
res.render(path.join(__dirname+'/views/home.ejs'), {counter: 2});
```

but same problem..

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
let path = require('path');
```

to the start of your script.

Then, in your `app.js` write:

```
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "..", "views"));
```

instead of just "`app.set('views', __dirname);`".

And in your `routes.js` write:

```
 res.render('home', {
     counter: 2
 });
```

Comment: I get: `Failed to lookup view "home" in views directory "A:\john\Documents\Visual Studio Code\PHP\Raz2\config\views`

Comment: Whats the absolute path to your `home.ejs`? The path should be correct. Try adding the file extension to `res.render` like `res.render('home.ejs', { ...` to make sure express takes the correct rendering engine

Comment: I tried with the extension too and didn't works. The path structure is what you see in the image above

Comment: I don't mean the the folder structure. I mean the absolute math. Like, is `A:\john\Documents\Visual Studio Code\PHP\Raz2\config\views\home.ejs` the absolute path of your file?

Comment: I guess it should be `../views/home.ejs` because if you look at the folders structure you can see that the file `home.ejs` is located in the `views` folder which is placed in the root directory...

Comment: Maybe I see the problem `dirname` return the folder `config` which is where is contained the file `router.js` so that's why the path is wrong, is there a way to access to the root folder?

Comment: Thanks this works, an info on the fly: is a good idea create a file called `constants.js` and place in that file some variables such as: `app.locals.baseUrl = path.join(__dirname, '..');`?

Comment: Not sure actually. I've always called files relatively. global var's for paths probably aren't a good idea

Comment: Why not? If I store only the root path dir I guess is a good way to go